# How to display last 7 days dates

Tags: python

how to print last 7 days dates like this:

```
  2020-04-27
  2020-04-26
  2020-04-25
  2020-04-24
  2020-04-23
  2020-04-22
  2020-04-21
```

How can I do this.

Comment: We would like to see first what you have attempted. Look at the `datetime.timedelta` and `datetime.date` classes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

now = datetime.now()

for x in range(7):
  d = now - timedelta(days=x)
  print(d.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))
```